# How to get arrays from sting?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to get an array from strings

```
const id = 1,8,10
output = ['1','8','10']
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are separated by `,` u can split the string like this:

```
const id = '1,8,10'
const output = id.split(',')

console.log(output)
>>> ["1", "8", "10"]
```